# Segment git project into submodules

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-subtree

I have a git project that is currently growing and several parts are starting to become projects in their own right.

So, I want to create submodules for them, but preserve the history of the files. There were moves between the different folders (eG from `partThatIsNotItsOwnProject` to `partThatIsItsOwnProject` and I'd like to have the history for that move too.)

Before:

```
/.git
/someFiles
/partThatIsItsOwnProject
--/subdirectory
/partThatIsNotItsOwnProject
--/subdirectory
```

I'd like to have:

```
/.git
/someFiles
/partThatIsItsOwnProject
--/.git
--/subdirectory
/partThatIsNotItsOwnProject
--/subdirectory
```

So, I guessed `git subtree` would do that, but it seems to keep the original git repository and only display a part of it. `git submodule` seems to be the target of this setup, but how do I do the transition?

Answer (score 1):

To do so you'll need to rewrite history of whole repository to exclude everything that is not related to directory you want to put in a separate repo. The `git filter-branch` command is useful for that. You can find an example of script that does that at [0]. Note that you might need to adjust it to your needs.

In general, `git filter-branch` [1] allows you to rewrite git history by applying your filters to every commit in the repo sequentially. Note that although using `--tree-filter` is the simplest way to achieve what you need, it is extremely slow as it does proper checkout of every commit along the way, so editing index directly with `--index-filter` is better.

[0] https://github.com/openstack/oslo.tools/blob/master/filter_git_history.sh

[1] https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch

Answer (score 1):

Fork you main git, then rename the forked into "partThatIsItsOwnProject", and then remove everything that is not part of that "subdir".
Then add the forked git as a submodule to your main git, all history is preserved.

Repeat for all subdirs that you would like to breakout from the master git.